# Creating an Equation with Summation and Constants in R

Tags: r

I was hoping someone could evaluate this code in which I am seeking to create a Random Variable Z using a Uniform Variable U and numerous Constant variables within a summation.

I have U(0,1) and constants a<sub>0</sub>=2.51..., a<sub>2</sub>=0.01, and b<sub>0</sub>=1...b<sub>3</sub>=0.0013.

and based on if U is > or < than 0.5 we get either Z<sub>1</sub> or Z<sub>2</sub> in return. My code is below!

```
w <- (sqrt((-2)*(log(U))))
a[1] <- 2.515517
a[2] <- 0.802853
a[3] <- 0.010328
b[1] <- 1
b[2] <- 1.432788
b[3] <- 0.189269
b[4] <- 0.001308
U <- runif(1)
if(U<=0.5) {
  print(ZOne <- ((-w)+((sum(((a[i])*(w^[i])), i=1, 3))/(sum(((b[j])*(w^[j])), j=1, 4)))))
} else {
  print(ZTwo <- ((1)-(((-w)+((sum(((a[i])*(w^[i])), i=1, 3))/(sum(((b[j])*(w^[j])), j=1, 4)))))))
}
```

Hope this makes sense, just for reference ZOne = [image: ZOne] , when U=<0.5.
ZTwo is (1-ZOne), when U>=0.5.

If you need any clarification please just let me know. Thank you!

*PS, I somehow need to create 1000 of these variables (Z), and figured I would just use the `replicate` for that.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use 0-based indexing in R. Also, your use of the `sum()` doesn't make sense. As a start, fix the various syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally started from zero based on the paper the issue is based on. Should be fixed above.

I used the understanding of sum from this link (http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/) where summation from 1 to n of x[i] is: `sum(x[i], i=1, n)` . Guessing I implemented it wrong?

Comment: I think you should write down the equation you are trying to code. Is `U` in the first line is same as `U <- runif(1 )`?

Comment: What you have produces no output whatsoever. It isn't valid R. Things like `w^[j]` or  `sum(a[i], i =1,3)` just aren't valid R syntax. Your code seems to be a cross between R and either some sort of pseudocode or an unspecified computer algebra system.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think the OP is asking help to code their equation.

Comment: Sorry, clearly my experience with R is very minimal. I'll try and post the equation more clearly in the main post now.

Comment: You really need to learn to code and write a question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- numeric(3)
b <- numeric(4)

a[1] <- 2.515517
a[2] <- 0.802853
a[3] <- 0.010328

b[1] <- 1
b[2] <- 1.432788
b[3] <- 0.189269
b[4] <- 0.001308

U <- runif(1)

# You can't use U before it exists!
w <- (sqrt((-2)*(log(U))))

# Here assuming w^2 in your equation is w * w etc.
# if not, remove ^(1 : length(a)) and ^(1 : length(b))
ZOne <- (-w) + sum(a * w^(1 : length(a)))/sum(b * w^(1 : length(b)))

if (U<=0.5) {
  print(ZOne)
} else {
  print(ZTwo <- 1 - ZOne)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are trying to do:

```
Z <- function(){
  w <- sqrt(-2*log(runif(1)))
  a <- c(2.515517, 0.802853, 0.010328)
  b <- c(1, 1.432788, 0.189269,0.001308)
  ZOne <- -w+sum(a*w^(1:3))/sum(b*w^(1:4))
  ZTwo <- 1 - ZOne
  if(runif(1)<=0.5) {
    Zval <- ZOne
  } else {
    Zval <- ZTwo
  }
  Zval
}
```

R operates on whole vectors. Using indices (`i,j`) is frequently a sign of poor design. Perhaps you might want to spend a certain amount of time reading a tutorial on R programming. By making it a function, you can use `Z()` to create random variates at will. E.g. something like `replicate(1000,Z())` will create 1000 such values.